# pyQiwiP2P pay_sources: list[str] = None

Tags: python, payment

I need to make payment via qiwi

```
from pyqiwip2p import QiwiP2P
from pyqiwip2p.Qiwip2p import PaymentMethods  

def create_trans(amount=400, lifetime=30, comment="def"):
        p2p = QiwiP2P(auth_key="I specifically removed")
        bill = p2p.bill(amount=amount, lifetime=lifetime, comment=comment, bill_id=random_id, pay_sources=[PaymentMethods.qiwi, PaymentMethods.card, PaymentMethods.mobile])
        return bill
```

**The program ends with an error:**

```
File "G:\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\pyqiwip2p\Qiwip2p.py", line 118, in QiwiP2P    
pay_sources: list[str] = None,
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks to be a bug in pyQiwiP2P.

As per your traceback, [line 118 of pyqiwip2p.Qiwip2p.py](https://github.com/WhiteApfel/pyQiwiP2P/blob/4760b788edb36ac01fb354cd2b82780c43e4e4e1/pyqiwip2p/Qiwip2p.py#L118) is as follows:

```py
        pay_sources: list[str] = None,
```

This contains a broken type hint, `list[str]`. It seems the author wanted to add a type hint saying that the method parameter `pay_sources` should contain a list of strings. In this case, they should write

```py
        pay_sources: typing.List[str] = None,
```

or perhaps

```py
        pay_sources: typing.Union[typing.List[str], None] = None,
```

instead, given that `pay_sources` can also be `None`.

To confirm this is the case, we can easily reproduce your exception in a Python interactive session:

```
>>> def test(a: list[str]):
...     pass
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

I would suggest you get in contact with the package author, perhaps by raising an issue on the [project's GitHub repository](https://github.com/WhiteApfel/pyQiwiP2P).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are using a version of python later than 3.9. I solved this problem by downloading an older version of the pyQiwiP2P library before deleting the one that was already on my PC:

```py
pip uninstall pyQiwiP2P
pip install pyQiwiP2P==2.0.1
```